# iTextsharp landscape mode print by default

Tags: itext, landscape

[image]I am using iTextsharp third party tool to generate PDF.

When I am generating pdf in Landscape mode, it is also  working. But issue with that when I am printing it prints in portrait mode. If I change the mode to landscape when I print then it works great.

I need mode in Landscape mode and don't need change in mode manually.

By using this code I am generating PDF.
var doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge this is not possible. In Acrobat (and most other renders), once you hit the "Properties" or "Advanced" buttons everything displayed is specific to the device being printed to. The most basic cross-device settings are exposed on the initial page and these are pretty much the only ones that you can programmatically set.